# Python ternary order of operations

Tags: python, ternary-operator

```
[on_true] if [expression] else [on_false]
```

If `expression` is `False`, does `[on_true]` still get evaluated?

Reason I ask is because I have a django ORM query as the `[on_true]` and will write this another way if it evaluates every time this line is run.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: A simple test `print("x") if False else print("y")` will yield only `y`

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After the truthiness of the condition is checked, only one side of the conditional expression will be evaluated. This is guaranteed and documented in the language reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

You can put whatever garbage expression there to convince yourself of the fact:

```
>>> wtf.errorerror - error + 1/0 if False else "potato"
'potato'
```

Comment: thanks, I should've realized and done the experiment myself